# I want to remove newline(\n) at the last from each line in a fixed widh flat file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a fixed width flat file where I am generating output rows. It has a header, a body  and a Trailer. The issue is if I generate the file using informatica power center then a newline(\n) is created after the end of fixed file widh but the requirement is to create Carriage return (\r) and newline(\n) just after the end of the data. So I am creating the (\r and \n) side by side using code but the extra new line(\n) is also getting created at the end. How can I get read of the last new line character?  I have given Presnt and What needed picture, can somebody give me a one liner sed command code to achieve this?

[image: Presnt]

[image: What needed]

Comment: Is your question simply about converting a text file between Unix text format and DOS text format? This is best done using the `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` utilities.  It is not clear that there is an "extra" newline at the end of each line that you show. It could just be the way that  whatever tool you use displays newlines symbolically.  If a line had two newlines at the end of it, then every second line would be empty (there would be an empty line between each original line).

Comment: First, [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). Second, it is unclear to me what you are asking and want. Can you please edit your post to clarify? Ideally, you should show the sample data, and the desired output from the _same_ sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you want to remove "empty" lines -- lines with only whitespace:

```bsh
sed -i '/[^[:blank:]]/!d' file
```

- if a line *does not* have a *non-blank* character, delete it.

With BSD sed (aka on a Mac), -i needs an argument: `sed -i '' '...' file`